# How to Call Two Fields From One Model in Django View

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I now have a model and I want to display two fields of it in the same view.Then display them in the details template.But the result returns an empty in template.What is the best way to do that?

my model:

```
class Book(models.Model): 
   class Meta :
       verbose_name_plural = 'Books'
   category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, 
   related_name="apps")
   book_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,allow_unicode=True,editable=True)
   book_title = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True)
   book_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='imgs' , null=True)
   book_description = RichTextUploadingField(null=True,blank=True)
   book_size = models.CharField(max_length=20 , null=True)
   book_created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   book_updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
   book_auther = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
```

my views:

```
 def book_details(requset ,book_slug):    
     book = get_object_or_404 (Book, book_slug = book_slug)
     try :
         book = Book.objects.filter(book_slug = book_slug)
     except :
         raise Http404
     similar_books = Book.objects.filter(book_auther = book_slug)  ------ >>> Here is my query

     context ={
        'book' :book,
        'similar_books':similar_books,
      }
  return render( requset,'book.html',context)
```

my template:

```
<div class="row">
{% for b in book %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{ b.book_picture.url }}" class="Rounded circle Image" height="150" 
            width="150" alt="">
            <a href="{{b.get_absolute_url}}">{{b.book_title}}</a>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="row">
{% for sb in similar_books%}
        <div>
            <img src="{{ sb.book_picture.url }}" class="Rounded circle Image" height="150" 
            width="150" alt="">
            <a href="{{sb.get_absolute_url}}">{{sb.book_title}}</a>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this? `Book.objects.filter(book_auther__icontains=book_slug)`

Comment: result returns empty in template my friend

Comment: Are you sure that in your database you have books that match book_auther and book_slug passed by parameter?

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
book = get_object_or_404 (Book, book_slug = book_slug)
```

this is a get method, which returns a single instance of book if found (not a Queryset)

Then you are repeating the same thing, and in my opinion this piece of code can be discarded since it's a duplicate of the row above

```
 try :
     book = Book.objects.filter(book_slug = book_slug)
 except :
     raise Http404
```

Then in the template you don't have to cicle on book: that's a single object not an enumerable - queryset, so you should write

```
<div class="row">
        <div>
            <img src="{{ book.book_picture.url }}" class="Rounded circle Image" height="150" 
            width="150" alt="">
            <a href="{{book.get_absolute_url}}">{{book.book_title}}</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

About your second query, based on your example data you cannot extract data with a filter, but have to process in this way:

```
similar_books = []
for sb in Book.objects.all():
   if sb.book_author in book_slug:
      similar_books.append(sb)
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, my friend, but I think you do not understand my question. I am not facing an error in the first query, but in the second query about how to display similar books

Comment: Sorry did not realize. But is your second query returning an empty queryset ? in effect book_author = book_slug seems a strange query.....
What do you logically mean by "similar books" ?

Comment: book_author like tags as it contains a lot of similar slug words.

Comment: Please provide sample data in your question, otherwise it's difficult to catch your point

Comment: book_author=Charles Dickens | book_slug=Oliver-Twist-by-Charles-Dickens | book_slug=David-Copperfield-by-Charles-Dickens. like that my friend.

Comment: You want pass `book_slug=Oliver-Twist-by-Charles-Dickens` and obtain all books when `book_author=Charles Dickens`? ¿book_slug is unique field?

Answer (score 0):

Insisted of using **filter(book_slug = book_slug)**  use **__icontains with Q object** (use the each word in book_slug inorder to get maximum similar entries).
for example : -

```
  slugs = book_slug.split() # which will give list of slugs

  condition = Q(book_slug__icontains=slugs[0])
  for slug in slugs[1:]:
     condition &= Q(book_slug__icontains=slug)
  Book.objects.filter(condition).all()
```

if you wish to eliminate explicit loop like above you can use **operator** to do that.

```
import operator

slug_conditions = reduce(operator.and_, [Q(book_slug__icontains=slug) for slug in book_slug])
queryset = Profile.objects.filter(slug_conditions).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try obtain list ahuthor book by first query and in second query filter all books with same authors

```
   book = Book.objects.filter(book_slug=book_slug)
   authors = book.values_list('book_auther').distinct()
   similar_books = Book.objects.filter(book_auther__in=authors)
```

If you want exclude book from simiar books

```
   book = Book.objects.filter(book_slug=book_slug)
   authors = book.values_list('book_auther').distinct()
   book_ids = book.values_list('id', flat=True)
   similar_books = Book.objects.filter(book_auther__in=authors).exclude('id__in'=book_ids)
```

Comment: thank yoooooou very much my friend. It works exactly as I want it to. This is what I really need. Thanks again.